# Firebase deep link not tracking link after app is downloaded on iOS (deferred deep link)

Tags: ios, firebase, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links, deeplink

Currently, I'm having issues where if users do not have the app downloaded and they click on the deep link, it brings them to the app store. After the app is downloaded, the app is open automatically, however it follows the regular sign up flow and it doesn't track the deep link.

Whereas if the app is downloaded, it will call continueUserActivity: and handles the flow where if the user is signed in/signed out.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I don't think you can track it

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that deferred deeplinking is handled in application:openURL:options:for iOS versions 9.0+ and Universal deeplinking is handled in application:continueUserActivity:restorationHandler:

I also updated my Firebase SDK version to 2.1.0

This was my output of [FIRDynamicLinks performDiagnosticsWithCompletion:nil] before implementing:

```
---- Firebase Dynamic Links diagnostic output start ----

Firebase Dynamic Links framework version 2.1.0

System information: OS iOS, OS version 10.2.1, model iPhone

Current date 2017-09-13 22:42:52 +0000

AutomaticRetrievalEnabled: YES

ERROR: UIApplication delegate <TalktalaAppDelegate: 0x1740b3860> does 
not implements selector application:openURL:options:. FDL depends on 
this implementation to retrieve pending dynamic link.

Specified custom URL scheme is com.talktala.talktala and Info.plist . 
contains such scheme in CFBundleURLTypes key.

AppID Prefix: 29998V6LPA, Team ID: 29998V6LPA, AppId Prefix equal to         
Team ID: YES

performDiagnostic detected 1 ERRORS.

---- Firebase Dynamic Links diagnostic output end ----
```

After:

```
---- Firebase Dynamic Links diagnostic output start ----

Firebase Dynamic Links framework version 2.1.0

System information: OS iOS, OS version 10.3.3, model iPhone

Current date 2017-09-14 16:43:26 +0000

AutomaticRetrievalEnabled: YES

Specified custom URL scheme is com.talktala.talktala and Info.plist contains such scheme in CFBundleURLTypes key.

AppID Prefix: 29998V6LPA, Team ID: 29998V6LPA, AppId Prefix equal to Team ID: YES

performDiagnostic completed successfully! No errors found.

---- Firebase Dynamic Links diagnostic output end ----
```